# VBA Save cell address before adding an offset value and use the saved cell address

Tags: excel, vba

I would like save the cell address into a range variable before I add an offset and move the focus away from the current cell, but come back to use that save cell address.

Here is what I am doing:

```
        Dim tempCell as range
        Worksheets("Deliverable-Epic-Story Progress").Cells(4, 1).Activate
        tempCell = ActiveCell.Address

        ' tempCell has a value of $A$4 

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Select 
        ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="XYZ.com"

        Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7)).Merge
        ActiveCell.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.AutoFit
        ActiveCell.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
```

After this piece of code, I want the control to select $B$5. I want to leverage the tempCell's value of $A$4 and add an offset (1,1). I do not know how to do this.

**UPDATE**
Jimber, I am still unable to select $B$5. The focus is going to I5 because it is treating the merged cell as active cell.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to select the cell you have already saved the address of.

`Dim tempCell as Integer`

`tempCell = ActiveCell.Row`

`’All your other code.`

`Cells(tempCell + 1, 1).Activate`

Comment: I believe you meant to say Range(tempCell).activate

Comment: That’s right. sorry. I just edited one of my previous answers and forgot to change that.

Comment: No cookie. It is not selecting the cell $B$5. See my screengrab above.

Comment: Does that work? I’m not at my computer right now, so I couldn’t test it.

Comment: Side note: Use `Long` instead of `Integer`.

Comment: Your latest changes (making the tempCell an integer/Long did it for me). Thank you for your support.